# Is there a way I can use button in react to delete a item in an array that is stored in the state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to build a ToDoList app and I have two components. I have a main component that handles the state and another button component that renders a delete button next to every task that I render. The problem I have is that i cant seem to connect the delete button to the index of the array and delete that specific item in the array by clicking on the button next to it.

I have tried to connect the index by using the map key id to the delete function.

just need help with how my delete function should look like and how its going to get the index of the item that is next to it and delete it.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      userInput: '',
      toDoList : []
    }

    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.delete = this.delete.bind(this);

  }
  handleSubmit() {
    const itemsArray = this.state.userInput.split(',');
    this.setState({
      toDoList: this.state.toDoList.concat(itemsArray),
      userInput: ''
    });
  }

  handleChange(e) { 
    this.setState({
      userInput: e.target.value
    });
  }

  delete(id) {
    this.setState({
      toDoList: this.state.toDoList.filter( (item) => id !== item.id )
    })
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <textarea
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          value={this.state.userInput}
          placeholder="Separate Items With Commas" /><br />
        <button onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Create List</button>
        <h1>My Daily To Do List:</h1>
        <Button toDoList={this.state.toDoList} handleDelete={this.delete} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}; 


class Button extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);    
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ul>
                {
                    this.props.toDoList.map( (item) => <li key={item.id}>{item.text}  <button onClick={this.props.delete(item.id)}>Done!</button></li> )
                }
            </ul>

        );
    }
};
```

Comment: could you give your code example?

Comment: delete(id) {
this.setState({
  toDoList: this.state.toDoList.filter( (task) => task !== task.id )
});

Comment: class Button extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        
    }
    handleDelete(e){
        this.props.handleDelete()
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ul>
                {
                    this.props.toDoList.map( (item) => <li key={item.id}>{item.tex}  <button onClick={this.handleDelete(item.id)}>Done!</button></li> )
                }
            </ul>

        );
    }
};

Comment: how are you passing the handleDelete prop to the Button component?

Comment: <Button handleDelete={this.delete} /> this is what i did in the main component and in the button component i just did handleDelete(e) {this.props.handleDelete()}

Comment: I just edited my post and put up the code, please take a look and let me know what i am doing wrong

Answer (score 2):

I reviewed your edited code and made a couple of changes.

I don’t get what exactly you want to achieve with you `handleSubmit` method but items it adds to the list are simple strings and don’t have neither ‘id’ nor ‘text’ properties you’re referring to in other places. Possibly you’re going to change this later but while your to do items are just strings I’ve edited your code so that it work properly under this condition.

Edited `delete` method now accepts not item.id as a parameter but the whole item object. Yet I'm using functional form of setState as it was correctly suggested by @Hamoghamdi

```
delete(itemToDelete) {
    this.setState(state => ({
        toDoList: state.toDoList.filter( (item) => itemToDelete !== item)
    }))
}
```

Edited `render` method of `Button` class now displays items as text and properly bind delete handler...

```
render() {
  return (
      <ul>
          {
              this.props.toDoList.map( (item) => <li key={item}>
                  {item}
                  <button onClick={() => this.props.handleDelete(item)}>Done!</button>
                </li> )
          }
      </ul>

  );
}
```

BTW `Button` is a bad naming for the component that isn’t exactly a button. Yet it’s better to implement it as a functional component. Use class components only if the component has its own state.

Comment: I reviewed your code and made a couple of changes to it (see my edited comment above)

Answer (score 1):

you should try using an anonymous function with `setState()` instead of returning an object literal directly, specially when you want to do something affected by the previous or current state

using `this.state` inside of `setState()` won't give you any good results.

here, try this:

```
delete = (id) => {
this.setState((prevState) => { 
return { toDoList: prevState.filter( (task) => id !== task.id )}
});
```

Comment: how would I connect this code to the button component

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the method in constructor for example:

```
constructor(props) {
  //...
  this.handleDelete = this.handleDelete.bind(this)
}
```

also you can find another ways how to bind methods

Answer (score 0):

In terms of handling the deleting the items, you can use

```
handleDelete(index) {
   // Use the splice array function: splice(index, deleteCount)
   this.todoList.splice(index, 1);
}
```

And that is all that easy